# How to limit a setter to be available to only specific classes?

Tags: typescript

I have 2 classes that depend on each other. For the sake of example, let's say that the structure is:

```
class AuthMiddleware {
    public authenticate() {
      // uses PostgraphileRouter here to extract some data before the authentication

      // authenticates ..

      // keeps the userId if authentication succeeded
       this.setSessionData(userId);
    }

    private setSessionData() {..}
    public getSessionData() {..}
}

class PostgraphileRouter {
  // makes a graphql query that uses AuthMiddleware.getSessionData()
}
```

I don't want to work with co-dependent classes, so I decided to put 
`setSessionData()` and `getSessionData()` in a `SessionManager` class and inject it to both classes.

The problem is that now I have to make `setSessionData()` public although I want to keep it available only to `AuthMiddleware` class.

1. Is extracting common code to another class is the best practice when
   dealing with co-dependency?
2. If it is, can I make some functions (such as `setSessionData()`) available only to specific classes?

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called `friend` classes in C++, which does not exist in typescript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847399/friend-class-in-typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is extracting common code to another class is the best practice when dealing with co-dependency?

Yes, it is common but can come down to a matter of preference and coding styles.

> If it is, can I make some functions (such as setSessionData()) available only to specific classes?

`interface`s can help you out here.

Example:

```
interface SessionDataGetter {
    getSessionData(): any;
}

interface SessionDataSetter {
    setSessionData(data: any): void;
}

class SessionManager implements SessionDataGetter, SessionDataSetter {
    getSessionData() { return null; }

    setSessionData(data: any) { }
}

class AuthMiddleware {
    // has access to both get and set
    constructor(sessionManager: SessionManager) { }
}

class PostgraphileRouter {
    // only has access to the get method
    constructor(sessionGetter: SessionDataGetter) { }
}

const sessionManager = new SessionManager();
const middleware = new AuthMiddleware(sessionManager);
// still same instance of session manager, but won't have access to setter (at least at compile time)
const router = new PostgraphileRouter(sessionManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the great answer of @Soc could be to create SessionData as [Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable), which can only be subscribed by the reading components.