# Javascript: allow certain classes to change properties of another class

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have Student class. The student has a grade.
Teacher class can change the student's grade.
Other classes (i.e., parent class) cannot do that. I think I get the part about how to change another class's property (please correct me if I'm wrong), but how to make sure that only the Teacher class can change the grade?

```
class Student {
 grade = 'A';

 changeGrade(grade) {
  this.grade = grade
  return `the new grade is ${this.grade}`
 }
}

class Teacher {
 changeStudentGrade(student, grade) {
  return student.changeGrade(grade)
 }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847399/friend-class-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not support this functionality. However, you can still add suitable logic to facilitate it by checking the class that is trying to `changeGrade` within the method as follows:

```
changeGrade(grade, classChangingGrade) {
   if (classChangingGrade instanceof Teacher) {
     this.grade = grade
      return `the new grade is ${this.grade}`
   }
 }
```

Then this method should be invoked as below:

```
return student.changeGrade(grade, this);
```

**Disclaimer**

Other classes can get around this by creating a new Teacher instance and invoking `changeGrade` as follows:

```
student.changeGrade(grade, new Teacher());
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this doesn't stop anyone else from writing `student.changeGrade(grade, someTeacher)`.

Comment: Very true, I will add this as a disclaimer.